# Python seek file signatures in corrupt files

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I’m trying to locate a file signature in a file that is open as binary in python. I need to search for a valid file signature, and once found, read the rest of the file from the file signature onwards into a new file.

I can locate the file signature in the open file okay using a list of file signatures which I have read from a text file using this method;

```
file_sig=line.decode('string_escape')
```

I am struggling with a method of reading the file signature position once I have located it. For example, I have found a valid Microsoft office file signature in a corrupt test file.

`\xD0\xCF\x11\xE0\xA1\xB1\x1A\xE1`

but need to read from this point on to the end of the file and output to a new, hopefully readable file. Any help would be, as always really appreciated

Comment: when you find the line you want to write from open a new file and start a new loop over the  file object and write. The file object returns its own iterator so you will start from that line